# Matching filesystem paths but not URLs in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match any filesystem path, but not any URL (I'm assuming URLs start with *http*). For instance, I'd like to match any path whose filename extension is *svg* unless is preceded by *http*, so that *hei.svg* matches but not *http://hey.svg*

My (probably) closest attempt is

```
'(?:(?!http))(\S+\.svg)'
```

and

```
re.findall('(?:(?!http))(\S+\.svg)', 'hey.svg')
```

> ['hey.svg']

but

```
re.findall('(?:(?!http))(\S+\.svg)', 'http://hey.svg')
```

> ['ttp://hey.svg']

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

**EDIT**:

I'm struggling to *finetune* the regex to also match a file whenever it is surrounded by newline's

> blah blah \nfoo.svg\n blah blah

or html tags

```
<br>foo.svg<br>
```

I took a shot at the latter (which seemed easier), but I can't even get that one to work:

https://regex101.com/r/rHsdOx/1

I'd like the last two lines to also yield a match.

Any further clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path should not start with http and contain `.svg`

```
(?<!\S)(?!http)\S+\.svg(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?!http)` Assert not http directly to the right
- `\S+\.svg` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and `.svg`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MX0lY9/1)

If the path should contain `.svg` you can change the `(?!\S)` to `\S+`

```
(?<!\S)(?!http)\S+\.svg\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GJppY9/1)

**Note** that using `\S` assumes the path does not contain a whitespace char.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much!! Also, I didn't know about this regex webpage (pretty cool).

Comment: Any help with the EDIT is appreciated